# When an execution opening occurs

Tags: javascript

Javascript is a single thread when executing.
So a piece of code is executed when there's free resource.
However what is a piece of code considered?

**a statement:**

```
var a = null;
```

**a block**

```
{
   a();
   b();
   c();
}
```

I wonder when there would be a possible openning for a triggered event callback when the event has occured before the end of `f()` execution?

```
function f(){
   a();
   b();
   asyncDef();
   c();
   d();
}
```

Until `f()` is execuded or let's say after `c()` has finished?
When will be the first possible opening?

Comment: The title almost sounds like what to wait for if you are an out of work executioner.

Comment: *"Until `f()` is execuded or let's say after `c()` has finished?"* Why would it be after `c()`? Did you mean `d()`? Any synchronous flow of code will need to complete before anything asynchronous can execute.

Comment: I mean that the event has occured when `c()` is executing so would the async code executed after `c()` or the thread is still occupied by `f()`

Comment: @kidwon: I posted an answer below, but basically `f()` will complete in its entirety, but not additional async code that may be called from `c()` or `d()`. So no, it will not slip in between `c()` and `d()`.

Answer (score 1):

Any synchronous flow of code will need to complete before anything asynchronous can execute. In your `f()` exmaple, the `f()` will need to entirely complete, including calls to each function inside.

However, if one of those calls triggers something asynchronous, that async code will not delay the rest of `f();`, nor the current async code that is waiting.

Answer (score 1):

A piece of code is both statements and blocks. The best way I can think to explain it: Use Developer Tools in a browser and step through code. The "piece of code" will be all the code you get through when a certain event happens.

If javascript is inline on the page, it is parsed and executed as a "piece of code". When events happen, the callback function is executed as a piece of code.

Once you are in the execution context, everything happens synchronously and an opening won't be available until the piece finishes. For example:

```
function f () {
  var d = new Date().getTime(),
      later = d + 5000;

  //Execute code as soon as there is an "opening"
  setTimeout(function () {
     alert("There was an opening.");
  }, 0);

  //Simulate work being done for 5 seconds.
  while (d < later) {
     d = new Date().getTime();
  }

  //implicit return here.
}

f();
```

You can see that the code (the function f in this example) is using resources until d surpasses later variable. The setTimeout pushes the anonymous function onto the event queue and will be executed when the resources are free (mainly after f completes). You can see that the timing is approximately 5 seconds.

[Async JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1937785270) is a short, but very informative book that explains a lot of these workings. [John Resig's blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) also does a good job of explaining timers (which you can extend the idea for browser events).